# How to install cvxpy on Mac M1?

Tags: python, macos, installation, cvxpy

This is the process of installing cvxpy on Mac M1 (since **pip install cvxpy** is not working directly):

step 1: install Homebrew

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

step 2: install cmake

`brew install cmake`

step 3: install cvxpy

`pip install cvxpy`

Comment: I think you should post this as an answer to your own question, not as a question. But maybe you should include what problems are you facing when installing it via pip.

Comment: I tried to edit accordingly, but it seems the great "peer-review" system said no :) Best, ~~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cvxpy website has [addressed the problem](https://www.cvxpy.org/install/index.html#apple-m1-users) directly. To summarize, there is no problem using pip for versions 1.1.19/1.2.0 and above, as long as:

1. cmake is installed via Homebrew.
2. ECOS version 2.0.5 is installed (as of 23.09.22, [more recent version seem to generate issues](https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/issues/1190#issuecomment-994613793)).

Here are the steps to install cvxpy on Mac M1:

step 1: install Homebrew

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

step 2: install cmake

`brew install cmake`

step 3: install cvxpy

`pip install cvxpy`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using

`brew install cmake`

and

`conda install -c conda-forge cvxpy`

I could not manage it with pip instead.
This was helpful: https://www.cvxpy.org/install/